# Web Server Log Analyse

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I have a web server log file I have to create a command-line pipeline to display the top ten most visited pages.

I then have to embed it in a shell script.

The log format is something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

Answer (score 4):

How about that:

```
grep -oP 'GET \K.*(?=HTTP)' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -rnk1 | head
```

- The `grep` regex catches everything between the `GET` and `HTTP` strings.
- `sort` then sorts the output
- `uniq` counts them
- `sort` again descending, numberical  and only the first field.
- `head` only prints the 10 first lines (the 10 most visited URLs)

Answer (score 3):

How about using established tools like "webalizer" or "awstats" ? You yould process the output of one of these two tools.